# Terminal is not responsive - `process completed`

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

Following on from my previous question ([[echo $PATH results in /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:](https://superuser.com/questions/1418364/echo-path-results-in-usr-local-bin-usr-bin-bin-usr-sbin-sbin-bin-bin-bi])) I have been commenting in bash_profile everything out and then I closed the terminal, opened it again. 
**Result**: now after the first character I type it says

- `process completed`

When I try to add another command, the terminal is non-responsive.
Why is it doing this?

I solved the problem by: open in finder the .bash_profile [pressed Command + Shift + > to show hidden files.], reversed the commenting. Terminal works again.
Still, I need to know, **why?**

Comment: What did you comment out to fix it?

Comment: Never mind my apologies the I failed to notice the previous question

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the other question, it looks like the `source .bash_profile` is to blame. Putting this in the `.bash_profile` causes it to infinitely loop executing the contents of the `.bash_profile` over and over again. If you remove this line it should resolve your issue. If this doesn’t resolve, I’d look for lines sourcing something in other bash config files.